# White screen showing up while calling fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android. So, I have been playing with fragments to understand how they work.

Firstly, I made a `calciKeyboard` class which extends `Fragment`

**Code:**

```
public class calciKeyboard extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    Button b;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        GridLayout gridLayout=(GridLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.calci_keyboard,container,false);
        for(int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){
            b=(Button)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (b != null) {
                b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_dark_gradient));
            }
        }
        return gridLayout;
    }
}
```

**calciKeyboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="4"
    >
    Buttons inside....
</GridLayout>
```

**advance_mix**

```
public class advance_mix extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.advance_length);
    }
}
```

**advance_length**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.tilak.myfirstapplication.calciKeyboard"
        android:id="@+id/calciKeyboard" />
</GridLayout>
```

**go_advance.java**

```
 findViewById(R.id.redirectLength).setOnClickListener(
              new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                      Intent i=new Intent(go_advance.this,advance_mix.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                  }
              }
      );
```

`go_advance` class contains the intent which starts the `advance_mix` activity, which further lays out the `advance_length` layout file.

The problem is when `redirect_length` button is clicked it shows me a white screen.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Find some online example for Fragments with activity and go through that example, you are doing all wrong.

Comment: do android:layout_height="match_parent" inside  advance_length.xml

Comment: I did read some tutorials, let me see again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `return` **View** .

```
  View getRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calci_keyboard,container,false);

   GridLayout gridLayout=(GridLayout)getRootView.findViewById(R.id._gridLAYOUT); 

          for(int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){
                    b=(Button)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    if (b != null) {
                        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_dark_gradient));
                    }

     return getRootView ;
```

**XML**

```
 <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/_gridLAYOUT">

  <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"  //Change this to match_parent
        android:layout_height="match_parent"   //Change this to match_parent
        android:name="com.example.tilak.myfirstapplication.calciKeyboard"
        android:id="@+id/calciKeyboard" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: @BOTJr. you can this. But your approach is wrong here.

Comment: white screeen , again?

Comment: Thing is `return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.calci_keyboard,container,false);` even doing this doesn't help.

Comment: `fragment` `layout height`  and `width` set to `match_parent` , it worked

Answer (score 0):

OK. Try to use "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" rather than "android.app.Fragment" and second think 'Button b;' declare before @Nullable

Comment: throwing up an exception